# On a density principle found in Gröchenig's book.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis

At the beginning of the appendix of the renown book by K.Gröchenig *Introduction to Time-Frequency Analysis*, there is a statement called *density principle* which I believe to be incorrect. I hope I will get some clarifications. This is particularly important because this principle is applied to prove other theorems in the book.

> **A.1 Density principle.** 
>   Let $X$ be a dense subspace of $B_1$. Assume that $A:X\to B_2$ is a linear operator that satisfies the inequality $$\|Af\|_{B_2}\leq C\|f\|_{B_1},\qquad \text{ for all }f\in X\qquad (A.1) $$
>   then (A.1) holds for all $f\in B_1$.

Here, $B_1$ and $B_2$ are Banach spaces. Notice that $A$ *is not assumed to be bounded on $B_1$*, and this principle is applied elsewhere in the same book without this assumption, so it is not just a typo.

**Why I believe the statement is incorrect.** If $X$ is infinite dimensional, then it is possible to construct a linear operator $A:B_1\to B_2$ such that $A$ is bounded on $X$, yet unbounded on $B_1$. See for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687907/unbounded-linear-operator-with-bounded-restriction)
 and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672626/unbounded-extension-of-bounded-operator).
 In this case, the inequality (A.1) cannot hold for all $f\in B_1$, yet it does hold for all $f\in X$ for a proper choice of the constant $C$.

**The proof proposed in the book.**

> For every $x\in B_1$ there exists a sequence $f_n \in X$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|f_n-f\|_{B_1}=0$. Since $\|Af_n-Af_m\|_{B_2}=\|A(f_n-f_m)\|_{B_2}\leq \|A\|_{\text{op}}\|f_m-f_n\|_{B_1}$, $(Af)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $B_2$. Therefore $Af_n$ converges in $B_2$ and we may define $Af$ by $Af=\lim_{n\to \infty}Af_n$.

**What I believe is wrong with the proof.**
This argument does not seem to prove the claim. We are starting with an operator that is already defined on $X$, so why would the proof conclude by redefining the operator $A$ on the whole space? This would make sense if we knew that the extension is unique. But this is only guaranteed if we assume that $A$ is bounded on $B_1$, which we have not.

What do you think, MSE?

EDIT: Actually the theorem is correct, although the sentence *$(A.1)$ holds for all $f\in B_1$* is rather ambiguous. The issue is that this princple is recalled when  proving another theorem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778419/extending-an-equality-from-a-dense-subspace-possible-mistake-in-a-proof)) where the operator $A$ was already defined on the whole $B_1$ (not just on $X$), so we cannot apply this principle since it requires to redefine the operator on $B_1\setminus X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement should be:

**Then $A$ has a unique extension to $B_1$ such that (A.1) holds for all $f \in B_1$**

with the proof as given.

Comment: Indeed, I see that this way the statement is correct. The issue is that in another theorem the author starts from an operator defined on the whole space (in this case $B_1$), proves that it is continuous on a dense subspace (say $X$), and deduces that it is bounded on $B_1$, appealing to this principle. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778419/extending-an-equality-from-a-dense-subspace-possible-mistake-in-a-proof

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: In this form, the theorem can’t be true, by the arguments you described. I do not have the book and therefore can’t check, but my guess is that the author wants to prove and then use the fact that you can *extend* the operator $A$ to a bounded one on $B_1$ (in fact, the operator norm stays the same) – at least that’s what the proof concludes. When he applies the theorem, is this result sufficient or does he really need that some given operator is bounded if it is on a dense subset?

Comment: No, he uses the principle as it is stated. See my other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778419/extending-an-equality-from-a-dense-subspace-possible-mistake-in-a-proof  here, he considers a linear operator that a priori is not bounded, checks that it is bounded on a dense subspace, and concludes that it is bounded on the whole space.

Comment: Actually, the principle is correct because here $A$ is only defined on the subspace $X$ and then one builds an extension to $B_1$ by defining it as stated in the proof. However, it remains that this principle is recalled when proving another theorem  (the one I linked in the previous comment) where the operator was already previously defined on the whole space and was not yet proved to be bounded

Comment: @LorenzoQ. I agree with you; the claim is written very ambiguously, inviting the mistake he apparently made in the theorem you linked...the situation over there reminds me of the classical Fourier transform: on the one hand, you have the version for integrable functions, on the other hand, you use some theory to define a Fourier transform for $L^2$-functions. We know that it is unitary and we know an explicit form in $L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but that’s about it. Gröchenig defines an operator on a dense subspace of $L^2$ and then claims some properties [1/2]

Comment: ........If, by some magic, his operator is actually well-defined on $L^2$, then you still have no idea why the extension should have the same properties on the whole of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. [2/2]

Comment: Sure. In the case of the Fourier transform on $L^2$ you *define* it as the limit of approximating sequences, so that is fine. However with the Short Time Fourier Transform he first defines it explicitly on $L^2$, and to prove that it is bounded, he proves that it is bounded on $L^1\cap L^{\infty}$  and uses this principle to conclude that it is bounded on the whole space. It is this, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Perhaps one could do a similar thing with the STFT: first define it on $L^1\cap L^2$, say, by the explicit formula, then extend it to $L^2$ in a continuous (i.e. bounded) way and lift the properties in this manner...it is too late for me to check, so it’s just a thought, really.

Comment: I agree, but this not what Grochenig does in his book. He first defines it explicitly, as the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function (through the integral), and then states this result. Anyway, even if one defined the STFT as the extension from $L^1\cap L^{\infty}$, proving that it agrees with the Fourier transform/integral representation would be exactly the same task. Besides, I have no doubts that the statement is correct, it is only the proof that is concerning.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much of an idea how to fix this issue...I wish I could have helped!